# How do I keep running a command in the same area of the console window? ("w")

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, console, w

I'm looking at the output of `w`:

```
ehryk@ArchHP ~> sudo w                                                                                                               
 14:12:37 up  4:08,  4 users,  load average: 2.18, 1.93, 1.55                                                                        
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT                                                                                 
ehryk    tty1      10:04    4:08m 57.70s  0.00s xinit /home/ehryk/.xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :0 vt1 -auth /tmp/serverauth. 
ehryk    pts/0     10:04    4:08m  0.04s  0.04s /usr/bin/fish                                                                        
ehryk    pts/1     10:04    4:06m  0.00s  0.00s bash                                                                                 
ehryk    pts/2     13:04   24:53   6.24s  0.00s x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -o conftest -O2 -I/home/ehryk/Projects/openwrt/staging_ 
ehryk@ArchHP ~>
```

However, the command exits. How do I keep running w in the same 'area' of the command line window, similar to the way `top` works, and control the refresh rate?

Comment: `watch w`. `man watch` for the refresh rate...

Comment: Thank you. 1) could you write that up in an answer, and 2) is there an option to not start at the top of the screen?

Comment: Sort of like `wget`, I suppose, where it updates the same line(s) without clearing the screen first.

Comment: Probably `watch` is not used for the same purpose in FreeBSD as suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/431363). You could follow the suggestion over there in that answer if you need portability in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `watch` command to constantly running `w` (every some time defined in `-n` parameter). For example:

```
watch -n 1 w
```

will run `w` every second.

Output of `w` will be kept on top of the terminal window.